# How can I set EntityState.Modified automatically for objects referenced through a navigation property when the parent object is modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my .NET MVC Web API project with EntityFramework I have these models; `Store` and `Course`. I override SaveChanges() in DbContext to increment a `version` property on each update.

What I would like to do is that when I update a `course` object, by changing the `location` property for example, I would like to increment the version property of each of the `store` objects that are referenced from the `course` object.

Is there any way to **automatically** set the `state` of the referenced objects to `EntityState.Modified` so the `version` property on these objects gets incremented as well or do I have to do it manually?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated if there's any other way I should be doing this.

Store:

```
public class Store : BaseModel {
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
    public int version { get; set; }
}
```

Course:

```
public class Course : BaseModel {
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<Store> stores { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext SaveChanges() Override:

```
case EntityState.Modified:
    dbEntityEntry.Entity.version += 1;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.GetType` in your overriden `SaveChanges` method to detect such a case and implement your logic from there.

If I understand correctly though, I'm not entirely sure this is the right way to do things;  this seems like pretty specific domain logic at first and should thus probably appear in a higher-level layer, not your DAL.

If your usage of `version` properties is systematic across all kinds of entities (not specific), then you might want to make a small abstraction layer on top of EF to handle your versioning needs.  I'm not aware of any such project around EF.  For this you would probably need to dive into the [Metadata Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx) to retrieve all navigation properties for a given entity.

But then again, I'm not sure how one would determine whether an associated entity's version should be bumped or not.  After that there's the depth/propagation problem, if the versions of the associated entities are bumped, should the versions of their own associated entities be bumped as well?  At first sight, it seems that this can't be generalized and is inherently domain specific.  I might be wrong.